# Por que a expressão `\`` === '`' é verdadeira?

Tags: javascript, string

Eu quero muito entender por que em JavaScript esse código dá `true`.

Não consegui entender essa lógica, alguém pode me explicar por favor?

```js
console.log(`\`` === '`');
```

Comment: A pergunta que tenho antes de ler as respostas é "por que não deveria ser?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dá `true` porque ambas as expressões geram a mesma string (no caso, é uma string contendo apenas o caractere `` ` ``). Veja:

```js
console.log(`\``); // `
console.log('`'); // `
```

No primeiro caso, o caractere `` ` `` é o delimitador de uma [*template string*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), então tudo que está entre os `` ` `` é parte da string. Por exemplo, `` `abc` `` gera a string "abc".

Mas e se eu quiser que o próprio caractere `` ` `` seja parte desta string? Para que ele não seja confundido com o delimitador, é necessário fazer o escape com `\`. Ou seja, quando é encontrada a sequência `` \` ``, o JavaScript entende que este `` ` `` não é o delimitador da string, e sim o próprio caractere `` ` ``.

No segundo caso, é uma string normal, delimitada por aspas simples. Sendo assim, o `` ` `` pode ser escrito diretamente dentro das aspas, sem a necessidade de escape, pois aí não tem como ele ser confundido com o delimitador (já que os delimitadores neste caso são as aspas).

E no fim, ambos geram a mesma string, contendo apenas o caractere `` ` ``.

---

Complementando, o mesmo vale se eu quiser ter aspas em uma string delimitada por aspas - por exemplo, `'\''` para gerar uma string contendo o caractere `'`. De forma geral, se eu quiser que o delimitador faça parte da string, tenho que usar o escape com `\` para que o caractere não seja confundido com o próprio delimitador.

Answer (score 5):

A barra invertida é só um caractere de escape, ou seja, em seguida vem um caractere especial, na prática só tem um caractere ali, a barra é só sintaxe para indicar a diferenciação.

Não é qualquer caractere que pode ser escapado. Os que podem são:

- ' - single quote
- " - double quote
- ` - backtick
- \ - backslash
- n - new line
- r - carriage return
- t - tab
- b - backspace
- f - form feed
- v - vertical tab
- 0 - null character

Se deseja que a barra seja considerada como caractere a ser incluso no texto e não ser usado como escape então deve usar `\\` que indica que a próxima barra invertida deve ser uma barra de texto mesmo.

Se você fizesse `` ` `` o que ele interpretaria? Ele abriria o gabarito do texto, fecharia em seguida e abria de novo sem fechar. Não é o que deseja. Com o `` \` ``, você abre o texto, tem um caractere de *backtick* que é igual ao abrir e fechar, mas como está escapado ele conta como o caractere normal e não como fechamento, e no fim, ele fecha o gabarito do texto como se espera.

O segundo texto é uma *string* normal então o abre e fecha é diferente do *backtick*, então não há ambiguidade e não precisa do escape.

Então o primeiro na verdade na memória é só um caractere de *backtick*, exatamente o que está no outro texto, portanto eles são iguais.

Answer (score 1):

Não só a template string

```js
(`\`` === '`') && ('\`' === '`')
```

também resulta no mesmo, já que a função do backslash \ é para encodar characteres especiais ou alguma sequência como **\n \b**, e \`
irá ser evaluado para `