# Caracteres especiais não são exibidos pelo console.log

Tags: javascript, string, característica-linguagem

Estou a resolver um exercício da escola e preciso imprimir uma string com caracteres especiais usando `console.log`, porém as `\` contidas na string são removidas ao executar o código.

Em busca da resolução do exercício, pesquisei sobre caracteres especiais em JavaScript e fui condicionado a pesquisar sobre expressões regulares. Encontrando apenas comandos que limitam uso de caracteres, e não que os permita.

Então como faço para o `console.log` exibir o `\`?

Segue código que escrevi de primeira mão:

```js
var myString = "If There Is Bread Winners There Is Bread Losers. But You Can\'t Toast What Isn\'t Real."

console.log(myString)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O caractere `\` não é "removido da string". Na verdade ele faz parte de uma [sequência de escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#escape_notation).

Basicamente, quando você cria uma string, tem que colocar o conteúdo dela entre aspas:

```
var string = 'conteúdo da string';
```

Mas e se eu quiser colocar as próprias aspas? Isso aqui não funciona:

```
var string = 'conteúdo 'da' string'; // errado!
```

Pois ao ver o `'` antes de `da`, o JavaScript entende que na verdade você está fechando as aspas, e portanto, encerrando o conteúdo da string. Neste caso, precisamos usar a sequência de escape `\'` para representar o caractere `'`:

```
var string = 'conteúdo \'da\' string'; // certo
```

Ou seja, a sequência `\'` é interpretada como o caractere `'`, indicando que ele faz parte do conteúdo da string e não deve ser tratado como as aspas que delimitam a própria string. Tanto que se você imprimir esta `string`, o resultado será `conteúdo 'da' string`.

Só que aí temos outro problema: se o `\` é usado para sequências de escape, como fazer para representar o próprio caractere `\`? Simples, com outra sequência de escape (no caso, seria `\\`):

```js
console.log('can\'t'); // can't
console.log('can\\t'); // can\t
```

No código acima, `\'` é a sequência de escape que representa o caractere `'`, portanto a string resultante é `can't`. Já `\\` é a sequência de escape que representa o caractere `\`, por isso o resultado é `can\t`.

Se você quiser que a string resultante seja `can\'t`, aí terá que escapar ambos:

```js
console.log('can\\\'t'); // can\'t
```

Ou seja, temos `\\` (que representa o caractere `\`) seguido de `\'` (que representa o caractere `'`), resultando em `can\'t`.

---

Vale lembrar ainda que se você usar aspas duplas (`"`) para delimitar a string, aí não precisa escapar o `'` (mas o `\` ainda precisa):

```js
// o ' está com escape
console.log("can\'t");  // can't
// mas dentro de aspas duplas, não precisa
console.log("can't");   // can't

// mas o \ precisa
console.log("can\\'t"); // can\'t
```

---

Por fim, regex não tem nada a ver com isso. Regex seria usado se você quisesse detectar tais caracteres e/ou removê-los da string, por exemplo (ainda sim, para casos mais simples nem precisa de regex). Mas se for para gerar uma string com tais caracteres, basta entender como funcionam as sequências de escape.

---

Ver também: [Por que a expressão `\`` === '`' é verdadeira?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/467687/112052)

Answer (score 4):

Uma alternativa seria usar o método estático [`String.raw()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) como uma função tag para uma [template literal](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) contendo o seu texto:

```js
var myString = String.raw`If There Is Bread Winners There Is Bread Losers. But You Can\'t Toast What Isn\'t Real.`

console.log(myString)
```

A documentação diz que como tag `String.raw()` é similar ao prefixo `r` no Python ou o prefixo `@` no C# para string literais. Onde é usado para pegar as strings no formato "cru" de template literais, onde substituições são processadas, mas sequencias de escape não são.

Há também [outros casos de uso](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw#exemplos) de `String.raw()` que fogem ao escopo da pergunta.

> *A documentação do método **faz o alerta** para um [bug que houve no chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=5016) e veja em sua tabela de compatibilidade que até o momento o método não é suportado pelos [navegadores IE e Opera](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw#browser_compatibility).*

```js
//Situações que geravam bug no passado.
console.log(String.raw `\x5c`);
console.log(String.raw `с:\x.js`);
```

Outra possibilidade também é criar a [própria função tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_template_strings) retornando a propriedade especial `raw`, disponível no primeiro argumento da função:

```js
function r(strings, ...values) {
  return strings.raw[0];
}

var myString = r`If There Is Bread Winners There Is Bread Losers. But You Can\'t Toast What Isn\'t Real.`

console.log(myString)
```

Essa abordagem é mais [compatível com navegadores modernos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#browser_compatibility) só não funcionando no IE.