# resposta = input("Digite \"S\" para continuar: ").upper() Porque é necessario colocar as duas barras invertidas entre as strings durante um input

Tags: python, string, input, syntax-error

```
resposta = input("Digite \"S\" para continuar: ").upper()
```

nesse caso se eu não colocar as duas barras invertidas o python reclama e acusa erro

Comment: Se vc não coloca a barra invertida, ele vai achar que o `"` está fechando as aspas e portanto terminando a string. Usando o escape (é o nome que se dá a barra invertida), ele entende que é o caractere `"`. Ver também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/467687/112052

Answer (score -1):

A barra invertida, em python, é um caractere de escape dentro de uma string. Ela serve para dizer pro interpretador "ignore o próximo caractere".

No seu caso, se você não colocar as barras invertidas, seria como se a string fosse "Digite " e depois tivesse alguma informação que não era para estar ali. Por isso o erro de sintaxe.

De qualquer forma, não é "necessário" colocar as barras invertidas.

Esse código compila e produz o efeito desejado:

```
resposta = input("Digite 'S' para continuar: ").upper()
```

Assim como esse:

```
resposta = input('Digite "S" para continuar: ').upper()
```

O que, realmente é necessário, é você não confundir o interpretador, usamos as aspas que usou para definir uma string dentro da própria string. Mas, caso seja você precise fazer isso, as barras invertidas resolvem.

Comment: O escape não serve para ignorar. Na verdade ele indica uma sequência de escape, ou seja, a barra invertida junto com o próximo caractere é uma sequência que é interpretada como um único caractere. Ex: `\"` é interpretado como o próprio caractere `"` (em vez do fechamento da string), `\n` é interpretado como quebra de linha (a sequência `\n` representa um único caractere, o n não é ignorado), etc